# Update parent from iframe using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have this minimal test case

a.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="myinput">
     <iframe id="frame" src="b.html" style="width:100%;height:100%" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
     </body>
</html>
```

b.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <script>
        function update_parent(value) {
            window.parent.document.getElementById('myinput').value=value;
        }
    </script>
    <a class="tag" name="something" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="update_parent(something)"/>Bla Bla</a>
    </body>

</html>
```

The purpose here is to update the input box in parent window, when a button is clicked on the iframe. I tried to do it using plain javascript as you can see above, but it doesn't work either. I want to do this using jquery if possible.

Comment: Works good for me: http://jsfiddle.net/HVBZD/

Comment: jQuery is not a complete replacement for javascript. You don't need to replace everything for this.

Answer (score 11):

```
function update_parent(value) {
    $('#myinput', window.parent.document).val(value);
}
```

The second parameter for the $() wrapper is the context in which to search. This defaults to document so passing the parent sets the parent as the search context.

Answer (score 0):

Your parent element would be window.self.top
You can access the contents or the document of the parent element.

Having said that, your code should look like:

```
$(window.self.top.document).find('#myinput');
```

This will give you the element in your parent.